# Why make_unique and make_shared uses parenthesis and not curly braces?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I.e. all implementations of the Standard Library (in MSVC, clang, gcc) use the following code (simplified for readability):

```
template<class T, class... Args>
inline unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

But why not curly braces? I.e.:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
inline unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return unique_ptr<T>(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
    //                        ^ here and                  ^ here
}
```

(Same question for `make_shared`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because those 2 implementations will behave differently in certain cases. The standard library must choose one of the semantics to make it consistent.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class... Args>
inline std::unique_ptr<T> my_make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}

int main() {
    auto a = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(12);
    std::cout << a->size() << "\n";

    auto b = my_make_unique<std::vector<int>>(12);
    std::cout << b->size() << "\n";
}
```

Here `a` is a `vector` of size 12, `b` is a `vector` of size 1 whose value is 12.

Answer (score 5):

Because curly-braces does different things depending on what `T` is and what constructors it has defined.

If `T` have a constructor taking an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) argument, then that constructor will be called when using curly braces. Which isn't really what is intended.

Comment: Except when it is what's needed, in which case you can provide the braces yourself, as in `std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>({2,3})`

Comment: @aschepler: except that it won't compile as `{2, 3}` won't be deduced...

Comment: This answer I believe is correct. I recall reading a discussion somewhere about the issues of methods like this when it comes to constructing a  `std::vector` which can do very different things when you provide two integer arguments if you use braces vs parentheses